# If n distinct objects are distributed randomly into n distinct boxes, what is the probability that exactly two boxes are empty?

Tags: combinatorics

My approach:

There are two configurations possible:
$$
0031111... \tag{1}
$$
$$
0022111... \tag{2}
$$
Where the numbers represent the number of objects in the each box for n boxes.

Step $1$: Choose the empty boxes
$$
\binom{n}{2}
$$
Step $2$: We solve for case $(1)$
Step $2.a$: Choose the box where $3$ distinct items will go:
$$
\binom{n-2}{1}
$$
Step $2.b$: Now, we have a sequence of assignments of the objects to their corresponding boxes. We permutate them:
$$
\frac{n!}{3!}
$$

Step $3$: We solve for case $(2)$
Step $3.a$: Choose the $2$ distinct boxes which will have $2$ distinct objects each:
$$
\binom{n-2}{2}
$$
Step $3.b$: Now, we have a sequence of assignments of the objects to their corresponding boxes. We permutate them:
$$
\frac{n!}{2!2!}
$$

Final answer:
$$
\binom{n}{2}\left( \binom{n-2}{1}\frac{n!}{3!} + \binom{n-2}{2}\frac{n!}{2!2!} \right)
$$

I am highly doubtful of this approach. Especially Steps $2.b$ and $3.b$.

For getting the probability we divide the answer by: $n^n$

Comment: You still need to divide count of proper distributions by total number of distributions.

Comment: After two zeroes, why does it start with $31$ ?

Comment: Step 2.b: There are ${n\choose 3}$ ways to select 3 objects and $(n-3)!$ ways to distribute other objects in $n-3$ boxes.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu ${n \choose 3}(n-3)!=\frac{n!}{3!}$ as in step 2b

Comment: Formula gives correct number of proper distributions. For probability, divide by total number. Probability is highest at $n=6$ and highest probability is slightly greater than 1/2.

Comment: @trueblueanil $0031..$ is just a visual representation of one possible permutation for the given config. Nothing special in the placements here.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu I forgot to divide by the total number. But I was worried about total number of proper permutations. Are you sure that the reasoning for the same which I have provided is right?

Answer (score 2):

*Just so you have an answer:*

Your approach works, though there are others. I think it can be simplified to $$n! \dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(3n-5)}{48}$$ which you then divide by $n^n$ to get a probability. Clearly you need $n>2$ to get a positive probability.

Another is to use $$\dfrac{n!\,S_2(n,n-2)}{2!\;n^n}$$ where $S_2(n,k)$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) counting the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ objects into $k$ non-empty subsets.  You get the same result.  If you wanted $n$ total boxes with $x$ distinct items then the probability of $y$ empty boxes would be $$\dfrac{n!\,S_2(x,n-y)}{y!\;n^x}.$$

Comment: Thank you. I need to check these Stirling numbers to understand what you mean here though.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach and computations are ok, and Henry has given you a slick way of computing it using Stirling numbers of the second kind, the only problem is that you need recourse to a table of Stirling numbers.

but if there are just one or two cases, instead of computing in the way you have done, you can streamline each case as the product of two multinomial coefficients, viz

[Lay down pattern]$\times$[Permute pattern]

So for case 1, taking $n=10$, say, it would be

$$\dbinom{10}{0,0,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}\times\dbinom{10}{2,1,7}$$

Also, know that the above formula has an **exact** equivalent
using permutations, (which is more familiar to most), thus

$$\dfrac{10!}{0!0!3!1!1!1!1!1!1!1!}\times\dfrac{10!}{2!1!7!}$$

This approach is a mechanical one, so you won't get doubts of the type you were getting in "building the pieces"

Of course, for probability you will have to divide by $10^{10}$, you know that